# how to hide menu item in toolbar (view pager, nested fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

here's my problem:

I have one `activity` with `toolbar` and `view pager` which contains three main `fragments` and two of them has nested `fragments`:

- [1] RootMapFrag,

  - MarkerMapFrag,
  - HeatMapFrag,
- [2] RootListFrag,

  - ListFrag,
  - WebViewFrag,
- [3] GraphFrag.

In `ListFragment` I created menu with search button for filtering `recycler view` which was implemented in that `fragment`. In my whole app I have only that one button initialized in `ListFragment`. `Search button` is working fine, but it's visible also on [1] and [3] tab. Is there a way to hide it from these tabs? I was trying to implement `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` with setting `menu.getItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false)` and `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in `fragments` which don't need this menu item but it's no use. Any ideas how to achive that? Here's my code:

`RootListFragment`

```
public class RootListFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_root_list, container, false);

        fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.root_list_fragment, new ListFragment()).commit();

        return view;
    }
}
```

`ListFragment`

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

        ...

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

`GraphFragment`

```
public class GraphFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);

        ...

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.getItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Here's gif from my app:

[image: add]

Answer (score 0):

In the `Fragment` where you don't want to show any menu options, you need `setHasOptionsMenu(false);` in the `onCreate()`, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```